# What is Pytorch equivalent of Pandas groupby.apply(list)?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I have the following pytorch tensor `long_format`:

```
tensor([[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  4.],
        [ 0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  7.],
        [ 1.,  8.],
        [ 0.,  9.],
        [ 0., 10.]])
```

I would like to groupby the first column and store the 2nd column as a tensor. The result is NOT guranteed to be the same size for each grouping. See example below.

```
[tensor([ 1., 2., 3., 4., 8.]),
 tensor([ 5.,  6., 7., 9., 10.])]
```

Is there any nice way to do this using purely Pytorch operators? I would like to avoid using for loops for tracebility purposes.

I have tried using a for loop and empty list of empty tensors but this result in an incorrect trace (different inputs values gave same results)

```
n_groups = 2
inverted = [torch.empty([0]) for _ in range(n_groups)]
for index, value in long_format:
   value = value.unsqueeze(dim=0)
   index = index.int()
   if type(inverted[index]) != torch.Tensor:
      inverted[index] = value
   else:
      inverted[index] = torch.cat((inverted[index], value))
```

Comment: The result is NOT guranteed to be the same size for each grouping. Updated question.

Comment: For my purposes a `List[torch.Tensor]` will suffice, would something like this be doable? Updating question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  4.],
        [ 0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  7.],
        [ 1.,  8.],
        [ 0.,  9.],
        [ 0., 10.]])

result =  [x[x[:,0]==i][:,1] for i in x[:,0].unique()]
```

**output**

```
[tensor([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10.]), tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 8.])]
```